# TFS 2013 solution files missing. How to resolve?

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I just noticed that my .sln, .vssc, .csprog and my entire root of my main project is missing from TFS latest changeset and when I try to load or open the solution from the server, those files mentioned are missing so my project is screwed up now. how can I recursively restore all files including the solution and other files mentioned?

Comment: What do you mean"missing from TFS latest changeset"? Did some checkin a delete changeset?

Comment: no deletion. the files are just no longer there.

Comment: How do you get VS 2013 to add everything in the solution to TFS 2013?